# Get content of div by css class name

Tags: php, html, dom

Using dom I want to get content from some specific div.
My Current situation is this : I want to get content from site link whose html structure is as below. I want that css class data for my local database. I think this is possible only using dom.

Here is the code :

```
<div class="listing-info-right ">        
    <div class="list-card-field name-address">
    <div class="list-card-user">
        Mr Bimal Kumar Agarwal
    </div> 
</div>

<div class="list-card-field name-address">
    <div class="list-card-phone">
          +91-9386750700,+91-612-2530310,+91-612-2530311
    </div>
</div>

<div class="list-card-field name-address">
<div class="list-card-email">enquiry@elementguestline.com</div></div>
<div class="list-card-field name-address list-card-border">
<div class="list-card-location">28,, Nalini Aparment 4th Floor, Kidwaipuri, Fraser Road, Patna, 800001, Bihar</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I want to fetch data of div class named : list-card-user, list-card-phone and list-card-location.

Before I had done coding using dom with css id, but could not get anything with class name..!

Please help me with some code.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You need javascript or jquery.

Comment: everything is welcomed, I dont have any idea how to get this..!

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: I want to get content from site abc.com whose html structure is as mentioned above.
I want to fetch data of div class named : list-card-user, list-card-phone and list-card-location to save in my localhost database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the simple one, perhaps this helps you :)

```
<div class="listing-info-right ">
    <div class="list-card-field name-address">
        <div class="list-card-user">Mr Bimal Kumar Agarwal</div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-card-field name-address">
        <div class="list-card-phone">+91-9386750700,+91-612-2530310,+91-612-2530311</div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-card-field name-address">
        <div class="list-card-email">enquiry@elementguestline.com</div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-card-field name-address list-card-border">
        <div class="list-card-location">28,, Nalini Aparment 4th Floor, Kidwaipuri, Fraser Road, Patna, 800001, Bihar</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Output:**

```
<div id="myNamez"></div>
<div id="myPhonez"></div>
<div id="myLoc"></div>
```

**Using jQuery:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var namez='list-card-user';
    var phonez='list-card-phone';
    var locationz='list-card-location';
    document.getElementById('myNamez').innerHTML='namez';
    document.getElementById('myPhonez').innerHTML='phonez';
    document.getElementById('myLoc').innerHTML='locationz';
});
</script>
```

Here's the **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/alicera/cgq27vhb/)**

Comment: `<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
$ch = curl_init("url");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$cl=curl_exec($ch);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom ->loadHTML($cl);?>
<div id="myNamez"></div>
<div id="myPhonez"></div>
<div id="myLoc"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var namez='list-card-user';
    document.getElementById('myNamez').innerHTML='namez';
   });
</script>
`
Am I doing it correctly ..?

Comment: you said you need to know in javascript. Dom reference is here> http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.construct.php pls :p
so, clarify your question, :p

Comment: Thanks for your response.
My Current situation is this : I want to get content from site [link(]abc.com) whose html structure is as above. 
I want that css class data for my local database. I think this is possible only using dom.

Comment: I tried your script in comments by using dom in php and I got this: http://appacyber.net/appalab/script_testz/test3.php

Comment: Yes, the same.. Because there is error..! I asked here :P :D

Comment: Update your question to clarify then :p :v

Answer (score 3):

You can select your `div` with `document.getElementsByClassName` in Javascript. This will return an array of all the elements with that class, if you only have one occurence then simply get the first node.

```
var div = document.getElementsByClassName("list-card-user")[0];
```

The `div` variable now points to your `div`, you can use a bunch of functions on it to get different things. For example, if you want its content, you can do this :

```
var content = div.innerHtml;
```

**Edit** I used Javascript because your original question used the `Javascript` tag, which has been removed now with an edit.

Comment: In past I had done working using `$title= $dom->getElementById("abc");` and now situation is this is from site abc.com and I want that css class data for my local database.  Can you please elaborate with some full code of javascript mentioned here..! As I dont have much experienced in catching data with javascripts and echo them..!